# Social networking website- usage of GEDCOM in it

Tags: social-networking, gedcom

i have to develop one social networking website. i have to follow gedcom standards for that. someone told me you have to take care at time of database designing if you are going to use GEDCOM. so please anybody can help me out for material i can read before i start website development and things to be taken care. or from where i can have strucutre of GEDCOM? i dont know anything about GEDCOM

Comment: Any feedback is welcome! Please share your findings. Does GEDCOM fit with social networking?

Comment: See SQLite Tools for RootsMagic - https://sqlitetoolsforrootsmagic.com/ where the gedcom file is probably converted to sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's descibed in the [GEDCOM Standard release 5.5](http://homepages.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pmcbride/gedcom/55gctoc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

See [About Genealogy:Genealogy GEDCOM 101:What Exactly is a GEDCOM and How Do I Use It?](http://genealogy.about.com/library/weekly/aa110100a.htm)...